# Displaying a Shopify meta dimension with value and unit

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a meta field that is of type "Dimension"

When I display the field on my product page it shows:

`{"value":402.0,"unit":"mm"}`

I want it to display as `402mm` so I tried to do something like the following:

`{{ product.metafields.my_fields.box_height | dimension_with_unit }}`

But this doesn't work, and I cannot find anywhere how to do this.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1asxhnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `.value` on the end:

`{{ product.metafields.my_fields.box_height.value }}`

This will then display as `402mm`